# stringstream with recursive variadic function?

Tags: c++, recursion, variadic, ostringstream

I want to be able to combine multiple different arguments into a single string using ostringstream. That way I can log the resulting single string without any random issues.

I got this far:

```
template <typename T>
    void MagicLog(T t)
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void MagicLog(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;

        MagicLog(args...);
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void LogAll(int logType, T t, Args... args)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        MagicLog(t);
        MagicLog(args...);
        //Log(logType, oss.str());
    }
```

So I need to replace std::cout with the oss that I made in the LogAll function, I tried passing it as an argument to the other functions but it was complaining about a "deleted function"...

So: How can I get a recursive variadic function to accept another parameter, the ostringstream?

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: Full error was "error c2280 attempting to reference a deleted function", the only thing in the answer I didn't have was the & sign...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem. Just like what you did with your `LogAll` function, passing an `ostream&` as first parameter [works like a charm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac0e70c13e7a156f):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
void MagicLog(std::ostream& o, T t)
{
    o << t << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void MagicLog(std::ostream& o, T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    MagicLog(o, t);
    MagicLog(o, args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void LogAll(int logType, Args... args)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    MagicLog(oss, args...);
    std::cout << oss.str();
}

int main()
{
  LogAll(5, "HELLO", "WORLD", 42);
}
```

It was also possible to eliminate the duplicate code from your `MagicLog` function.

Comment: This is beautiful. I had something pretty similar but without the & sign, which might be some lack of my C++ knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: @ManIkWeet Yep, that might have been the problem. You can not pass an `ostream` by value (without the `&` sign) because that would mean copying and `ostream`s can not be copied.

Comment: Makes sense. Did not know that such thing could make so much issues.

Comment: After you edited you code, the example doesn't even compile. You forgot to remove `, T t` from arguments of `LogAll()`, and maybe `int logType` too since it's not used anywhere.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks, fixed. `int logType` comes from the question and it is a nice demonstration of how you can pass additional parameters.