# Simpler logger function using std::stringstream

Tags: c++, logging

I'm trying to write a simple logging function which can handle different types in this format:

```
LOG("This is one type: " << one_type << " and here is a different type: " << diff_type);
```

I've been looking at the examples here:

[How to use my logging class like a std C++ stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511768/how-to-use-my-logging-class-like-a-std-c-stream)

[stringstream with recursive variadic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080553/stringstream-with-recursive-variadic-function)

and this is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void LOG(std::stringstream& ss)
{
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

However, even when I just do:

```
LOG("Some text");
```

I get the error:

```
could not convert ‘(const char*)"Some text"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::stringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>’}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: stringstream does not have an implicit constructor that takes a string.

Comment: this looks pretty strange to me. why not use log as stream just like [your linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/511779/5980430)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to solve this is to make `LOG` a macro that just does text substitution instead.  You could define a `LOG` macro like

```
#define LOG(to_log) \
do \
{ \
    std::cout << to_log << std::endl; \
} while (false)
```

and then

```
LOG("This is one type: " << one_type << " and here is a different type: " << diff_type);
```

would get expanded to

```
do
{
    std::cout << "This is one type: " << one_type << " and here is a different type: " << diff_type << std::endl;
} while (false);
```

Comment: I personally would yet append `std::endl` – usually one wants to have each log entry on its own line anyway and I wouldn't impose that on the user...

Comment: @Aconcagua Good advice and the OP was doing that in their own code so I've added it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename ... T>
void log(T const& ... t)
{
    ( std::cout << ... << t );
    // maybe want to add a newline?
    std::cout << std::endl; // note: '\n' just adds it,
                            // std::endl flushes the stream... 
}
```

would allow to log (to console!) as:

```
log("this is an int: ", 1210, " and this is a double: ", 10.12);
```

Note the commas instead of the stream operator (`<<`)...

If you want to log to arbitrary streams you might need to add it as yet another parameter (`/*...*/ void log(std::ostream& s, T const&... t)`) or you might (among other solutions) initialise some singleton that you access from within the logging function:

```
void initialiseLogging(std::ostream& s)
{
    Logger::instance().initialize(s);
}

template <typename ... T>
void log(T const& ... t)
{
     // assumes returning a reference:
    ( Logger::instance().stream() << ... << t );
}
```

Above variant assumes initialisation being required and logging without yielding undefined behaviour (needs to be documented!). If you want to be able to log without you need to change:

```
{
    // now assuming a pointer being returned!
    auto s = Logger::instance().stream();

    // variant 1: log to nowhere if not initialised:
    if(s)
    {
        ( *s << ... << t );
    }

    // variant 2: default logging to console
    s = s ? s : &std::cout;
    ( *s << ... << t );
}
```